# Swift Firebase -How to block a phone number from posting to a certain ref

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is a food app, I let users post food. Before someone posts there is warning that says "food and drinks only, anything else and you will be banned from posting for life"

```
let dict = ["pictureOfCouchUrl...": "foodPic"]

let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)
postsRef.updateChildValues(dict)
```

In the above example this user posted a pic of a couch. I see it and now I want to ban this user from posting anything at this ref.

When a user signs up to my app they use their email address to create an account but before they post they have to verify their phone number which eventually links their email address and their phone to their uid. The phone number is only used for posting and to login they use their email address.

```
let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId, verificationCode: verificationCode)

Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { [weak self](authDataResult, error) in ...
```

I also let users completely delete their account which removes their email, phone number, and uid:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
user?.delete { (error) in
    if let error = error { }
}
```

The problem is if I want to block the uid of the user who posted the couch, all they have to do is completely delete their account, create a new one, and then get a brand new uid, which means this process can repeat itself. But if I use their phone number (which they will eventually have to register to post) to block them from the postsRef then even if they create a new account and get a new uid they still won't be able to post using that phone number (I don't see anyone changing phone numbers just to be able to post on my app).

How can I block a user from posting using their phone number? instead of their uid?

Here are my rules:

```
"posts": {
  ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a ref specifically for blocked phone numbers:

```
"blockedNumbers": {
  ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
 }
```

Whenever a user's phone number is blocked the number is permanently in that node. Even if a user deletes their account that phone number will always be inside there. Before a user posts I simply check to see if that phone number is in there and if it is they can't post.

```
let dict = // dict with data that needs to get uploaded

let userPhoneNumber = "+12125551212"

let blockedNumbersRef = Database.database().reference().child("blockedNumbers").child(userPhoneNumber)
postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.exists() {

        // show alert because this phone number is blocked
        return
    }

    // the phone number doesn't exist so go ahead and post
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)
    postsRef.updateChildValues(dict)
})
```